# How to use vi java api to specify IP address while deploying vm from ovf?

Tags: java, api, vmware, esxi

Is there a way I can configure the network setting (IP, gateway, etc) while deploying ovf to ESXi server ? Below is the code snippet I copied from vi java api sample code (by Steven Jin) that I used to create vm instance from existing ovf. Anyone know how to insert some lines to get the new IP/gateway configured ?

```
    OvfCreateImportSpecParams importSpecParams = new OvfCreateImportSpecParams();
    importSpecParams.setHostSystem(host.getMOR());
    importSpecParams.setLocale("US");
    importSpecParams.setEntityName(newVmName);
    importSpecParams.setDeploymentOption("");
    OvfNetworkMapping networkMapping = new OvfNetworkMapping();
    networkMapping.setName("Network 1");
    networkMapping.setNetwork(host.getNetworks()[0].getMOR()); // network);
    importSpecParams.setNetworkMapping(new OvfNetworkMapping[] { networkMapping });
    importSpecParams.setPropertyMapping(null);

    String ovfDescriptor = readOvfContent(ovfLocal);
    if (ovfDescriptor == null) 
    {
      si.getServerConnection().logout();
      return;
    }

    System.out.println("ovfDesc:" + ovfDescriptor);

    ResourcePool rp = ((ComputeResource)host.getParent()).getResourcePool();

    OvfCreateImportSpecResult ovfImportResult = si.getOvfManager().createImportSpec(
        ovfDescriptor, rp, host.getDatastores()[0], importSpecParams);
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

This is really a big one and not possible to answer here.

You have to learn about [Sysprep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sysprep) for windows VM. And for Linux you have create scripts for personalization. Then you can mount the disk and run this scripts to personalize.

Comment: Thanks Reuben. I'm using Linux. I wish I could get some specific hints that I can explore or some reasonable alternatives to think about.